# How to have a route accessed only from code and not from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I see that when we name a route in the config file, something like:

```
  match 'controller/posts' => 'controller#posts', :as => 'posts'
```

it creates a named route for the controller with that action.

But this route needs to be accessed from the code. Say when I click on posts button from view, it should execute this for the user.

But when someone executes www.xyz.com/posts, it should not try to execute this. Is that possible ?

Comment: Not 100% clear to me what you mean by "this route needs to be accessed from the code"? Are you asking for how to create a controller that will *only* respond to requests from HTML that you have previously rendered? Does your application already have authentication and user sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would go about it this way.  It sounds like what you want is to be able to call a specific bit of code from another controller.  So a route won't work for the reasons you mentioned (it will be available over the browser).

Instead, you should extract this bit of code and put it in it's own library.

**lib/foobar.rb:**

```
module Foobar
  def my_method
    # add your code here
  end
end
```

Then you can call it from whereever you want in your code.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to setup a route and deny access if someone entered in the URL in a browser instead of clicking on a link.

What it sounds like you are trying to do is prevent users from guessing a URL. There are several options to do this:

- Require authentication for the URL
- Use a unique token in the URL which is hard to guess (/posts/1122bbbbababab/1)

You can use [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication.

To use a token you can setup a route like:

```
match 'controller/{some unique token here}/posts' => 'controller#posts', :as => 'posts'
```

Have a look at the [Rails guide on Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) for other ways to set a constraint on a route.

Comment: Actually for a POST route it *is* possible to go a little further and for instance digitally sign the request, and/or use a nonce, so that only the previously rendered HTML form (or an automation of it) would work, via some extra hidden fields. That can be used to prevent repeat-request attacks. Not clear whether the OP would benefit from that, or is asking more fundamental security questions (which your answer addresses). Your suggestion of a unique token is pretty close to what I think the OP is asking.

Comment: Good point about POST requests and about nonce. That can be part of the URL request by using public/private crypto to generate a signed token which would be valid for a period of time (similar to the csrf-token rails generates). I'll update my answer with this.